# Disqus error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Cp::set_variable()

Tags: comments

trying to load the Disqus module and get this error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Cp::set_variable()

anyone else experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. CP::set_variable was deprecated in EE 2.6.

I'm submitting a fix to the addon's github repository